Problem when submitting EditForm after refreshing the browser
I have Blazor Web app with render mode InteractiveAuto.I have one Editform to validate the information from one table in database. After validating, It return some data to another Editform and some additional frields on it. Both Editform run as expected untill browser is refreshed. After F5, first EditForm gives error in  await httpClient.GetAsync() as bad request. It does not even go to controller. After inspecting I see method=post is missing from  after refresh so I added it:
<EditForm method="post" Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="VerifyStudent"> </EditForm>

It did not work.
Tried override OnParametersSetAsync. It did not work.
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
 {
     Model = new();
 }

Also, I noticed after browser refresh autofill form does not show suggestions, if that makes any difference.

There is simply not enough information to provide any sort of answer to this question.  See [MRE].

You need to add some necessary information, your httpclient configuration, log your form state, check your CSRF, check the browser network information, if controller is not hit while it is correct before refreshing, the model state is usually the issue.

I found that the problem was in Get request as I was passing an object to Get. When I separated parameters to Get an object, it was fixed. Now I am not sure how it was even working at the first place.

Your problem is more a complex model issue though you didn't mention. It might be the  caching or other framework reasons that it works at the first place when it is not fully rendered. You could refer to the documents to modify your model more reasonablely.
